# Python/SQLite: Use variables for table and field names or literal names?

Tags: python, sqlite

One can use variables to define table and field names:

```
_SCHEDULE_TABLE = "schedule"
_SCHEDULE_COL_ZONE_ID = "zone_id"
_SCHEDULE_COL_ENABLED = "enabled"
_SCHEDULE_COL_LEVEL = "level"
```

You can then use this to create the table:

```
f"CREATE TABLE {_SCHEDULE_TABLE} ({_SCHEDULE_COL_ZONE_ID} int, {_SCHEDULE_COL_ENABLED} int, {_SCHEDULE_COL_LEVEL} text)"
```

And run queries:

```
f"SELECT COUNT({_SCHEDULE_COL_ZONE_ID}) FROM {_SCHEDULE_TABLE} WHERE {_SCHEDULE_COL_ZONE_ID}='{zone_id}'"
```

This works well.  However, I can't help but think that it is unnecessarily complex.  The table and field names are not likely to change.  Is using variables for these identifiers actually a good practice?  I am looking at queries that could (should?) be simple strings turned into something far more complex to read.  And, of course, it is now code that needs to be parsed and executed before you have your query string.

The positive is that you can change table and column names as needed.  If this past development stage, you can't just do this without without consequences.  In other words, if it is a working database, the variables don't buy you anything in terms of being able to rename things.

I could see an argument for protecting from mistyping identifiers in a query.  However, a good IDE, like PyCharm, is smart enough to help you enter these identifiers into a string for a query through auto-completion.  This, for the most part, tells me the variables might be unnecessary.

The above query, then, would be written as:

```
f"SELECT COUNT(zone_id) FROM schedule WHERE zone_id='{zone_id}'"
```

Where the last `{zone_id}` is a parameter passed to a function or method.

**This is not about a subjective case for or against variables** but rather to understand if there's an objective reason to take one or the other approach and, if so, when.

One example of this would be if you take a performance hit because of using variables for every identifier.  I haven't found any such recommendations in the documentation.

Comment: I think it is more an opinion rather a answer.
First, please escape your query to avoid any SQL injection, using the module utilities to escape them. 
Second, it allows to be tracked by the python syntax, thus can be reused later, across files, functions, and so on. This allow for code inspection, and also allows to be able to read your code more easily (is this a reference to an object, a table, something ?).
Also, you could use a ORM (a declarative or not) if you want even more abstraction, they might be 'too complex' for your use case or provide a nice way to communicate with your db.

Comment: I am getting back into SQL after not touching it for decades.  For now I prefer to avoid ORM and force myself to get my head back into SQL.  Good point regarding escaping.  This is a single user desktop console application, so so real worries about injection.  Your point is valid though.

Comment: If you're getting back into SQL then type it all out to build your "muscle memory".

Comment: I am doing exactly that with every query on the console to test and confirm it is what I want.  I then re-enter it into Python while substituting identifiers with variables.  This is where I started thinking this might be unnecessarily complex.